# Como permitir valores nulos em um campo que era originalmente NOT NULL em SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Eu tenho uma tabela criada dessa forma:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Mas eu quero alterar o campo `usuarios.nome` para que, a partir de agora, ele permita valores nulos. Como funciona o `alter table` nesse caso?

Comment: `alter table TABELA alter column COLUNA null`? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver é utilizando o comando `alter table ... modify ...`. Para mais informações consulte o [`manual 5.7`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html), [`manual 8.0`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html).

Para executar o comando abaixo eu utilizei a definição do `create table` que está em sua pergunta.

Segue o DDL:

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios MODIFY COLUMN nome VARCHAR(64) NULL;  
-- Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
-- Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Uma segunda maneira:

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios MODIFY COLUMN nome VARCHAR(64);
```

Repare que omitimos a palavra `NULL` em relação à primeira.

Agora o DML:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email) VALUES(null, 'a@a.com');
-- Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email) VALUES('eu', 'eu@a.com');
-- Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

Utilizei o mysql 5.6 (via sqlfiddle), 5.7 e 8.0.22 (parceria @Augusto Vasques)

Comment: Exemplo com MySQL 8 https://paiza.io/projects/OPLOST4y9JHEZ1fV2ypjIA?language=mysql se quiser subir para a resposta fique a vontade para usar.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, vou subir a solução então, obrigado.

Comment: Olhei o código agora é identico, talvez não precise modificar. @AugustoVasques

Answer (score -4):

Basta remover o NOT NULL

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(64),
    email VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Por padrão, uma coluna pode conter valores NULL

Comment: O AP quer modificar os campos mantendo os dados. Se fizer dessa forma terá que excluir os dados para então criar uma nova tabela.